# I want to fetch count (*) for all tables in a DB at a time along with 'Table_Name' in DataBricks SQL

Tags: t-sql, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

For example, I want output something like this in Databricks.

[image: Table]

I know how to do it in SSMS or Oracle but that syntax is not working in Databricks. I tried using the 'show tables' but its not serving my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps-

```scala
 spark.range(3).createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
    println(spark.catalog.listTables().map(_.name).collect()
      .map(table => table -> spark.table(table).count()).mkString(", "))

    /**
      * (df1,3)
      */
```

### using `db_name`

```scala
 println(spark.catalog.listTables(spark.catalog.currentDatabase).map(_.name).collect()
      .map(table => table -> spark.table(table).count()).mkString(", "))

    /**
      * (df1,3)
      */
```

Comment: Thanks for info, but where can I specify DB name in this? as without giving DB name its taking too long to give any output.
Also will it make changes to the tables ?

Comment: see edit, feel free to accept + upvote if it help :)

Comment: > will it make changes to the tables ?  === No, all these are read-only operations

Comment: spark.catalog.listTables(<db_name>).map(_.name).map(table => table -> spark.table(table).count()).show(false) --> I used this , it is giving a message 'Unclosed Block'

Comment: full stacktrace?

Comment: It have created 26 spark jobs 4 stages each job and still adding jobs to list, in executing state for more than 5 mins. Seems its runs on entire cluster not just a database.

Comment: yeah its similar to counting all rows from the table individually